# Why are there so many zeros in the binary file?

Tags: c++, g++

Let me use this simple *Hello world* program as an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";
}
```

Compile using: `g++ hello.cpp`

From quick inspection of the binary file in a text editor, it seems that about half of the resulting binary is only zeros, most of them in large blocks.

I'm not worried about it but it seems odd that the compiler would waste a bunch of space. Is there a good reason for having these large unused blocks?

Comment: It's different on different systems but you can find one explanation by reading [`a.out.h`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?a.out(5)) - _"format of executable binary files"_

Comment: Half the bits, on average, are zero...

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well of course, but I'm not talking about individual bits ;). There are large blocks of several kB of just zeros.

Comment: *"half of the resulting binary is only zeros"* -- this should not seem unusual, as "binary" suggests only two values. Perhaps you meant "half of the **bytes** of the resulting binary are zeros?

Comment: *"the binary file in a text editor,"* -- text editors tend to be rather inadequate for viewing binary files, especially if the file has a large number of null bytes. Those bytes typically don't show up as ASCII text. Did you mean a **hex** editor instead? Something that shows the hexadecimal representation of the file?

Comment: @JaMiT Good point. I'm using sublime text, which basically functions as a hex editor when opening a binary file. I didn't think of the fact that most editors wouldn't play so nicely :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program file consists of some metadata, executable code, read-only data, data. Each of those is aligned to the page size of your system so that they can be mapped into memory. Those "large unused blocks" are just padding to bring everything to alignment. It's only looks large because your program is basically nothing.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically what I guessed, but I didn't know the exact reasons :P